# What does the word 「やそこら」mean?

Tags: translation, words, manga

Here is a sentence said by a boy who talked to an officer.

はてね　脱走未遂の罪は　たしか二週間ほどぶちこまれっぱなしときいていたが　まだ　十日**やそこら**しかたっていねえじゃんか

My translation as following, please also help me correct it if I'm wrong.

Well, I committed a crime of planning to escape from (in this case, a reformed school) so I have to be punished by being left (in this case, a room of repentance) for 2 weeks for sure, but it has not passed 10 days as yet.

I'm not sure if it means "or so".

Comment: I think it is 十日や + そこら. I'm not sure what や does here though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, ～やそこら is a colloquial set phrase meaning "～ or so". This そこら is the same そこら in [そこら辺](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%93%E3%82%89%E8%BE%BA). You can find many examples on [BCCWJ Corpus](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/).

This phrase tends to be used when the speaker thinks the number is small ("only around ～").

> - 彼女は10歳やそこらの子供に見える。 (implying 10-years-old is very young)
> - 500円やそこらの金で出来ることは限られている。 (implying 500 yen is small)

Your translation attempt is not literal, but you're on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

まだ　十日 や そこら しか たっていねえじゃんか

> 接続詞「と」と「や」の違い
> http://wingtrans.blog98.fc2.com/blog-entry-240.html
>
> A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar
> この文法書には「や」が次のように定義されています。
>
> - 「や」“a coordinate conjunction that is used to list two or more items (nouns or noun phrases) in an inexhaustive fashion” (p.536)
>
> そして「と」の定義は以下の通りです。
>
> - 「と」“a particle which lists things exhaustively”   (p.473)
>
> 上記の定義を比較すれば、両者の主な違いは直ぐに分かりますね。

----------------> inexhaustive   vs.  exhaustive

「や」is more inexact, informal.

I think  ら in そこら is the same as in  我ら, われら 【我等】

I wouldn't be too surprised to find the expression [ ... days and thereabouts ] in Dickens and the like.

Found it.  Ok, [or] is more inexact, informal.

> Barnaby Rudge, by Charles Dickens
>
> ocw.nust.na/gutenberg/9/1/917/917-h/files/relative.htm
>
> ...... His name was unknown, he had never been seen until within about eight days or thereabouts, and was equally a  ...